# Triggering a function in one app from another

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, ipad

I have a requirement where I download an invoice in App A. I have a printing App B. The invoice in App A needs to be printed using App B. Is there a way I can achieve this using swift ios?

Both App A and App B belongs to the same development team.

Answer (score 1):

You can not directly call another applications functions however you can launch the other application using a URL scheme (Create a URL scheme to handle printing invoices and the routing required if launched via the scheme) and pass the required information for the invoice to be printed.